# meaning of "stock" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It was a pleasant evening; Charles found it remarkably so, but I
> cannot tell why, unless the absence of Miss Terry, towards whom his
> conscience reproaches him with being now perfectly indifferent, was a
> relief to him. There were only twelve dances, of which I danced nine,
> and was merely prevented from dancing the rest by the want of a
> partner. We began at ten, supped at one, and were at Deane before
> five. There were but fifty people in the room; very few families
> indeed from our side of the county, and not many more from the other.
> My partners were the two St. Johns, Hooper, Holder, and very
> prodigious Mr. Mathew, with whom I called the last, and whom I liked
> the best of my little **stock**.

This is from [Jane Austen's letter to her sister Cassandra](https://lettersofnote.com/2015/12/16/i-drank-too-much-wine-last-night/).

What does stock mean in this context?

Answer (score 4):

Jane Austen's 'stock' here is her supply of available dancing partners for that evening.

> 1.1 A supply or quantity of something accumulated or available for future use.

[Stock (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stock)